# Trying to call a function 1000 times with replicate

Tags: r, function, call

```
simulate <- function(bankroll, bet, max_iterations) { #gambler's ruin function 
  iteration = 1 
  while (bankroll > 0 & iteration < max_iterations) {
    win <- sample(0:1, size = 1) #either loos or win 
    if (win) {
      bankroll <- (bankroll + bet)
    } else {
      bankroll <- (bankroll - bet)
    }
    iteration <- iteration + 1 
  } 
  return(list(c(iteration, bankroll))) 
} 

simulate(1000, 100, 100)
```

I am trying to call the above function 1000 times to get the vector.  Then I need to count how many of the iterations were less than 100. Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Please do not repeatedly post the same question. Consider deleting your [last one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64815638/hi-i-am-new-to-r-and-trying-to-do-gamblers-ruin).

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple version using base

```
simulate <- function(bankroll, bet, max_iterations) { #gambler's ruin function 
  iteration = 1 
  while (bankroll > 0 & iteration < max_iterations) {
    win <- sample(0:1, size = 1) #either loos or win 
    if (win) {
      bankroll <- (bankroll + bet)
    } else {
      bankroll <- (bankroll - bet)
    }
    iteration <- iteration + 1 
  } 
  return(bankroll)
} 

calls <- replicate(n = 1000,expr = simulate(1000, 100, 100))

calls_less_100 <- calls < 100

result <- length(calls[calls_less_100])

result    

probability <- result/length(calls)

probability
```

Comment: Hi Bruno, I am getting an error on line 2 calls_less_100<-calls < 100
Error: 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Comment: Sorry you need to change replicate function to just return bankroll

Comment: Thank you:) May I ask you a favor. I might have more questions can I ask you? I would like to learn.

Comment: Sure, if it is the same problem just ask here or else you can at me in new questions, you can also upvote and accept the answer

Comment: Thank you so much. I would like to find the probability now. I need to divide the result/bankroll from the return of the function. How can I get that bankroll when it is in the function and not in the environment ?

Comment: Added probability

Comment: HI Bruno I need some help in adding the counter=i to the function S<-function(n){
M<-4.132731
x<-double(n) 
i<-1
while(i<(n+1)){
C<-rcauchy(1) 
u<-runif(1)
temp<-(M^(-1))*(1/sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-C^2/2)/1/(pi*(1+C^2))
if(u<-temp){
  x[i]<-C
  i<-i+1
}
}
return(c(x,counter))
}

Answer (score 0):

This can simply be reduced to:

```
simulate <- function(bankroll, bet, max_iterations){
         bankroll + bet * sum(sample(c(-1, 1), max_iterations, TRUE))
}
```

Then you could do:

```
sum(replicate(1000, simulate(1000, 100, 100))<100)
```

Comment: Thank you Onyambu, Would you please explain what you did t me. I would love to learn correctly:)